# std::find, reverse or direct find depends on a param, elegant way

Tags: c++, stl

What's more elegant way for depending direction searching in an STL container than this?

```
iterator i;

if ( condition )
  i = std::find( begin, end, value );
else
  i = std::find( rbegin, rend, value ).base();
```

No C++11, boost is allowed.

Thank you.

Comment: ternary operator? why your variant is bad? what condition you use for determine direction?

Comment: @ForEveR: i don't think my variant is bad, just wondering if there is something better. ternary operator makes this code less readble i think.

Comment: @ForEveR: in term of readability. i don't consider this question like urgent one, my variant is a readble too i belive.

Comment: how could you assign both results to `it`? 
I thought first result is `iterator` and second one is `reverse_iterator`?
And why did you do `.base()`, I cant find this method in `std::find()`.

Comment: @MarsonMao: ``std::find`` with reserved iterators as the input parameters returns an reserved iterator.

Comment: yeah that's exactly what i meant. in your first case, `std::find` returns an `iterator`, and in the second case, it returns `reverse_iterator`. so how could you assign both of them to `iterator i`?

Comment: In the second case first i call ``base()``, it makes an forward iterator from reversed one and then there comes an assing to ``i``.

Comment: @fogbit besides that ternary is unreadable only when one doesn't wrap the condition in braces, in your particular case it would make the code *much* more readable: just two lines, brevity with no ambiguity, and as a bonus — though probably unneeded in the particular case — possibility to make `i` to be constant.

Answer (score 0):

If boost is allowed, you can use `boost::range` and [`reversed`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/reversed.html). That's a nice example where ranges can really be superior to iterators.

Comment: Could you give some example of using ``boost::range``, please? From what i've tried with ``boost::range``, i have to create two different types of iterator ranges depending on an original container iterator and ``boost::find`` returns two different iterator types, so i have no uniformed type of an returned iterator. Am i right?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do it at the moment. I'd suggest you read into `range` docs and examples a bit, and eventually post another question regarding that, if you find you really want to use it. It's still kind of experimental, I'd say.